# Disable androidX - flutter

Tags: flutter

So I am use a plugin which is not compatible with androidX I am wanting to disable androidx completely until I can figure out how to make the plugin androidx applicable.

Comment: I think you should think on the other way round. How can you make your plugins migrate to AndroidX. I think adding `android.enableJetifier=true` and `android.useAndroidX=true` on your `android/gradle.properties` should do that. Have you tried this?

Comment: @ShababbKarim No I have not as I did not code the plugin am using audio_stream_player which has not been updated for awhile

Comment: Yes. Totally understandable. But you should enable jetifier in **YOUR** android project. Then what happens is that all the libraries that your code depends on is automatically converted to AndroidX compatible imports.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this step: Tools>Sdk Manager-> Appearance &Behavior ->System Settings -> Android SDK.  then check the Show package details in the bottom right. Next, I check mark everything under android 7.1.1, next uncheck everything android 8 and above. the click apply. that way when you start a now project, you will have the option to uncheck androidx artifacts in the bottom after you select the activity.
hope this help